# Is it possible to check whether two objects collide without using "IntersectWith" syntax in winform c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I already know if we want to check whether two objects collide, we can use "IntersectWith" syntax. But in my homework, they didn't allow that and we must use logic to solve it. Is there any other way to check whether two objects collide only with logic ? (like array or position x and y or something like that)

Comment: try with `for` loops

Comment: What objects? Windows Forms is a UI framework, it has no concept of object collision and obviously no `IntersectsWith`. Classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace that deal with 2D drawing have intersection methods to check whether shapes intersect. This has nothing to do with object collision

Comment: [Rectangle Intersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Rectangle.cs,438) (.Net source code). Get inspired, don't copy :)

Comment: @Jimi a rectangle isn't an object. Besides, I suspect that's the `IntersectWith` method that the OP isn't allowed to use. I suspect the OP is taking a course in computational geometry (or games) and the lecturer ensured they didn't take "shortcuts" to avoid doing the assignment

Comment: i mean object like button collide with lable

Comment: @Verlanderstore that's where everyone asks `Have you tried anything?`. Calculating whether two rectangles intersect is trivial. Just compare the coordinates of the points. *Have* you tried to calculate the coordinates and compare them?

Comment: As long as both labels and button have a know shape (they are both square shaped) you can manually check their position (x,y) and dimensions (height and width) and detect if they overlap. Doing so you may become with and actual coding problem, with that we would be glad to help

Comment: If the object is not dynamic, i can use coordinates comparing. But how if they want me to check static button with dynamic lable (adding everytime with timer) collide. I can't do the check statement because it will refer to all lable not single lable that i want to check.

Comment: because i adding the lable with same variable name every time

Comment: "because i am adding the lable with same variable name every time" this is an XY problem. You  have a problem but are asking about a different one. In winforms you can check the controls added to the form looking at the form `.Controls` collection.

Comment: @Verlanderstore edit the question and add all the relevant information there, not the comments. Post your code, don't describe it. You started asking one thing, then another, and now iit's something completely different. `because it will refer to all lable not single lable` that doesn't make sense. If you already check coordinates, you already answered your own question and the current problem is a completely different one

Comment: @Verlanderstore this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X, assume Y is the solution and ask about Y when it doesn't work. What is the *actual* problem? Add that in the question, not in the comments

Answer (score 1):

Controls like Button, Labels, etc. have rectangular bounds.  When given two controls the Bounds property could be used to compute intersection which would give you the test for collision.  Below is one simple way to calculate rectangle intersection.

```
public bool DoesIntersect(Control c1, Control c2)
{
    return (Math.Min(c1.Bounds.Right, c2.Bounds.Right) >= Math.Max(c1.Bounds.Left, c2.Bounds.Left) &&
            Math.Min(c1.Bounds.Bottom, c2.Bounds.Bottom) >= Math.Max(c1.Bounds.Top, c2.Bounds.Top));
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Done.  Let me know if that feels like the right level.